# URL not resolved with APIView in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm starting out with DRF and ran into some trouble when trying to set up a simple APIView.

This is the view:

```
class SongSearchView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, query, format=None):
        return Response(['Justin Bieber - Boyfriend', 'Justin Timberlake - My Love'])
```

and these are the URL patterns:

```
router = DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^api/song_search/(?P<query>[a-zA-Z0-9\w]+)/$', views.SongSearchView.as_view()),
                   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
                   url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
                   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

and when I try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/song_search/?query=justin` I get a

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/song_search/?query=justin
```

What is the issue? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Url pattern Regular expression is wrong.. If you still want to stick to your current url pattern , I suggest you change your request url from
 `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/song_search/?query=justin`  to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/song_search/justin`

Comment: Oh of course, confused the regular expression with GET parameters.. Thank you!